# Flutter - Paystack Payment Gateway - How to add fees to Card

Tags: flutter

I integrated Paystack payment gateway to my Flutter-Woocommerce app. Everyhting works fine as in the integration and all. I'm however having a little challenge in the e-commerce app I'm building while trying to pass the total amount of the cart to Paystack "amount". Whenever I do so, the Paystack popup payment window does not open. Please what could be wrong? Here is my code

[image]

My debugger puts an exception here also. what does it mean? What should I do?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **[flutter_paystack](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_paystack)** ?

If not then use it. If Yes then first download sample example from their [Github](https://github.com/wilburt/flutter_paystack) Repo.

Run the example app and then integrate that part of code as per your need.

Comment: Yes that's the package I'm using